# How to destroy php session without log out

Tags: php, session, authentication, destroy

Here is the code I'm using to log in a user :

```
    if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password)
    {
        session_start();
        echo 1;
        header("Location: index2.php");
        $_SESSION['username']=$db_username;
```

Now, this is supposed to assign a session to the username who has logged in. In my application, I don't have a log out option so I go to the log in page and send another username and password. So when these new information are sent, the old session must be destroyed and a new session to the new user should be assigned. Can I do that ?

Comment: Just a note, place the `session_start()` on top of your script and the `header()` below the `$_SESSION`. Ideally there are no more code after `header()`.

Comment: yes you are right i am working on this, i will get back to you with results , thanks

Comment: @bsdnoobz okay did what you said and added session_destroy() before session_start(); but it still assigns the session to the old user !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write  `logout.php` and [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the session.

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is instead of using session_destroy (logout system) use the `session_unset` function to clear all session variables. Then use `session_regenerate_id()` to create a new session id and dump the old one(this is done automatically, you might have to send a 'true' boolean parameter along with that function), and assign new data to $_SESSION['username']

Check the docs for [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Comment: can you please tell me more details how to use session_unset based on my code ?

Comment: if u use, session_destroy() then most likely ull have to use session_start all over again. Now, if u plan to use another session without having a logout process, then just simply add session_unset(); This will clear ALL $_SESSION variables. Then, add session_regenerate_id(); This will replace the old session with a new session ID. Now you are ready to add whatever fresh values u want to $_SESSION. Using this method, you have essentially logged out the previous user and logged in a new one. get it?

Answer (score 0):

You should better use the session destroy method. It destroys all data which were stored into the session.

```
session_start();

//add some code of your app here

session_destroy();
```